# Custom Fields Best Practise

Tags: module, custom-options, custom, custom-field

I'm very new to Magento development, but i've migrated over from wordpress development.

One of the things I love most about wordpress development is how easy it is to make almost everything on the site customisable in the backend.

Whats the best practise for creating custom fields in the backend of magento which I can pull through into my custom modules?

I need to be able to create things like customisable menu's that are global on the site, but also create customisable fields that are unique to each page if I wanted.

Can someone point me in the right direction for the approach I should be taking, as I have no idea whats the correct way to achieve this and don't want to be wasting my time!

Comment: Magento is completely different from WordPress. Wordpress is a blogging tool (Ofcrouses it is being used as a ecommerce tool as well) whereas Magento is completely eCommerce shop software. in Magento its all about product, category and its attributes. You can add custom attributes from admin "Stores->Attributes->Customer, Product" etc. You can add an extension to create menu from admin. but to provide separate field on each page, you need to create a custom module. Without that it would not be possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice!